# How do I disable Google Chrome from using regional google search?

Tags: google, chrome-for-android, languages

I am using a [VPN app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=im.zpn)
 and I don't want google to give me Arabic searches if my VPN is Arabic (besides, the whole site is mirror-imaged, since Arabic is written backwards). I want every search on Google to go to either google.com or google.co.in. I have tried searching, but all of them are about Chrome in PCs, and not for Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installed the VPN app and checked

Easiest way is to choose an English speaking location like USA instead of app choosing the location in *auto mode*

Alternatively, use other search engines available under Chrome settings → search engine. It appears Chrome picks up default search engine based on [location](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en), which happened to be Arabic based on the choice of VPN

Answer (score 2):

You can visit these addresses below everytime you want to do a search or simply bookmark it. There is no way to add a custom search engine on the mobile Chrome version.

[Google Search No country redirect](https://www.google.com/search?q=%25s&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr) or [www.google.com/ncr](http://www.google.com/ncr)

And now when you search with Google Chrome, it will always search using Google.com in English without the country redirect.

Comment: "*There is no way to add a custom search engine on the mobile Chrome version.*" Big bummer. Is it possible to "pin" my country settings and forbid Chrome from changing country redirect?

Comment: i don't think that is possible.